# Hadoop on Ubuntu Desktop 13.04

Tags: hadoop

How do i install Hadoop on Ubuntu Desktop 13.04 (64 bit) running inside VMWare player on Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

The installation process is huge , to help you quickly I am giving the link

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

follow the above link which have everything about installation and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help you out, but its the same installing Hadoop on a VM as it is a physical machine.

http://mysolvedproblem.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-on.html

Its for a little older Ubuntu but the process should still be the same.

Comment: Or http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ which goes through the same process in a little greater detail.